# SSO autologin Wordpress + Ajax

Tags: ajax, cookies, authentication, nonce

That one keeps me awake at night.

The problem is that the user is properly logging in, but AFTER page refresh and should be immediately logged in without page reload. Need a fresh eyes to look at it.

Seems like a problem with proper setting up cookies and nonces, but not sure how to debug this.

Greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

```
function my_update_cookie($logged_in_cookie)
{
    $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] = $logged_in_cookie;
}
add_action('set_logged_in_cookie', 'my_update_cookie');

add_action('wp_ajax_create_user', 'im_ajax_create_user');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_user', 'im_ajax_create_user');

function im_ajax_create_user()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $usernameID = $_POST['userId'];
    $user_data = [
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_email' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $usernameID,
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        ];
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);
    if (isset($user_id->errors['existing_user_login'])) {
        $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
        $user_id = $user->data->ID;
    }
    do_action('set_logged_in_cookie');
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false, true);
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_get_current_user();
}
```

Comment: What do you need to be able to do that you cannot do with this code - what is the technical error that you need help with?

Comment: I want a user immediately logged in after using JWT token in URL parameter, like this https://example.com/?jwt=test_token . The token validation is already handled, and the decryption of the token is passed to the function above, the user is logging in but I need to do it without a need of page reloading. Tried to use wp_redirect after wp_set_auth_cookie which is setting a new page with cookie w/o reload, but since it is Ajax, this function is not working and the redirect can only be setup in JS, but JS is entirely reloading the page.

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are sent to the browser. The next time the browser sends a request for a page, it sends the cookie information back and the page can make use of it - it is not available without a new request being made.

Comment: What are the other solutions that could achieve no-refresh SSO on Wordpress?

Comment: AJAX - you can confirm the login worked, without needing to check for the existence of the cookie - as you are setting that based on the authentication process.

Comment: There are many examples on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752016/591486

Comment: Well, the above code is using Ajax, i'm probably still missing some additional call.